# Make cubes size smaller

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Please run snippet in `fullscreen` mode, then you see cubes are too big, I want to make it smaller:

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3qo1v8a7/)**

I have change `size` on `root` but it make a space between cubes, how can I make it small without make any space between?

```
:root {
  --hue: 185;
  --radius: 5.5;
  --size: 4;
}
```

I change it to:

```
:root {
  --hue: 185;
  --radius: 5.5;
  --size: 1;
}
```

**[After Change](https://jsfiddle.net/3qo1v8a7/1/)**

Comment: You can do it by `--radius: 2;`, but the speed is so fast. So I think `--radius: 4;` and `--size: 2;` is the best choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use this for example:

```
:root {
  --hue: 185;
  --radius: 4;
  --size: 3;
}
```

or

```
:root {
  --hue: 185;
  --radius: 3;
  --size: 2;
}
```

or even

```
:root {
  --hue: 185;
  --radius: 1.5;
  --size: 1;
}
```

---

It will also work when the `--radius` is 1.5 more than the `--size` (This works for every size)

For example:

```
:root {
  --hue: 185;
  --radius: 25.5; /* 1.5 more than the size */
  --size: 24;
}
```